# Facebook review Submission for "manage_pages" permission

Tags: facebook, submission

Can anyone please help me to submit to get approal for "manage_pages" permission..?

I haved tried on my best but always get the repsonse like:
"Your Page Tab links to a different Facebook URL. Go to the app "Settings" tab >> find the "PageTab" section >> revise your Page Tab platform."

As my case, I have an ecommerce system which allows users create an online store automatically by few step.

For example, ecommerce system is hosted at URL abcd.com. I create a store name "TEST", so I would get a sub domain test.abcd.com where I can access to my "**TEST**" store

So this means that, abcd.com just be a general domain, for each different store will have one separate sub domain

In PageTab section of my Facebook App, I config detail as below:
- Page Tab URL: http://abcd.com
- Secure Page Tab URL: https://abcd.com

I create a FanPage name "Testing FanPage 01" and try to integrate my store ( test.abcd.com ) to this FanPage

It works prefectly although the URL of page display in iFrame is test.abcd.com which totally different from the Secure Page Tab already defined before

The whole process can be explain as: when Facebook's proxy post to abcd.com , I will do some process to detect and redirect to test.abcd.com

I think, the problem is that the page URL displayed in iFame is completely different from the Secure Page Tab already defined before...?